# VB Runtime Encoding - For Loop won't count properly

Tags: vb.net, logic

I am developing a runtime encoding program. The program should take in a string and count the number of occurences of a character in a string, the number and character in a new string for each occurence of a different character. However, when I run this the first character type is counted properly and then the rest are one less than they should be as well as the last type of character not being added e.g.

```
-+=Input your Data stream=+-
nnnMMMnnMn
3n2M1n0M
```

Code Below:

```
Module Module1

Dim DataStream As String
Dim CompressedDataStream As String

Sub Main()

    RetrieveData()
    Console.WriteLine(CompressData(DataStream))
    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub

Sub RetrieveData()

    Console.WriteLine("-+=Input your Data stream=+-")
    DataStream = Console.ReadLine()

End Sub

Function CompressData(ByVal DataStream As String) As String

    Dim LengthOfDataStream As Integer = Len(DataStream)
    Dim tempChar As Char 'to store previous character
    Dim tempInt As Integer = 0 'to store number of occurences of character

    For iter = 0 To (LengthOfDataStream - 1)

        'check first character, store character
        'check next character if same character add one to tempInt

        If iter = 0 Then
            tempChar = DataStream(iter)
        Else
            tempChar = DataStream(iter - 1)
        End If

        If tempChar = DataStream(iter) Then
            tempInt = tempInt + 1
        Else
            CompressedDataStream = CompressedDataStream & tempInt & tempChar
            tempChar = String.Empty
            tempInt = 0
        End If

    Next

    Return CompressedDataStream

End Function

End Module
```

Any help would be appreciated, including different methods of achieving the same solution.

Comment: When you debug your code, i.e. set a breakpoint and step through the code line by line and examine the state at each step, exactly where and how does the actual behaviour first differ from your expectation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your and in jmcilhinneys Function the last count and char is missing as it is not appended **after** the loop.

```
Function CompressData(ByVal DataStream As String) As String

    Dim CompressedDataStream as New System.Text.StringBuilder()
    Dim tempChar As Char = Nothing 'to store previous character
    Dim tempInt As Integer = 0 'to store number of occurences of character

    For Each _c as char in DataStream
        If _c = tempChar Then
            tempInt += 1
        else
            If tempInt > 0
                CompressedDataStream.Append(tempInt & tempChar)
            End If
            tempChar = _c
            tempInt = 1
        End If
    Next
    CompressedDataStream.Append(tempInt & tempChar) ' Append after the loop

    Return CompressedDataStream.ToString()

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the fact that you should probably use a `StringBuilder` if there might be a large number of characters, here's how I would tend to do this:

```
Function CompressData(text As String) As String
    Dim output = String.Empty
    Dim previousChar = text(0)
    Dim count = 1

    For i = 1 To text.Length - 1
        Dim ch = text(i)

        If ch = previousChar Then
            count += 1
        Else
            output &= count & previousChar

            previousChar = ch
            count = 1
        End If
    Next

    Return output
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/linq/introduction-to-linq) and [String Interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/strings/interpolated-strings):

```
Module Module1
  Sub Main()
    Dim oOutput As IEnumerable(Of IGrouping(Of Char, Char))
    Dim aOutput As String()

    Dim _
      sOutput,
      sInput As String

    sInput = "nnnMMMnnMn"
    oOutput = sInput.GroupBy(Function(Chr) Chr)
    aOutput = oOutput.Select(Function(Group) $"{Group.Count}{Group.Key}").ToArray
    sOutput = Join(aOutput, String.Empty)

    Console.WriteLine($"Input: {sInput}")
    Console.WriteLine($"Output: {sOutput}")

    Console.ReadKey()
  End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Beware that string interpolation can be slow in a tight loop, so it might not be appropriate if it would involve a large input string.  Obviously, it wouldn't be an issue if your input strings will usually not be large.